# Why does TFS not report errors and warning generated in the MSBuild exec task?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, exec, tfsbuild

In my TFSBuild.proj I have the following Exec commands:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="@echo Program.cs(12,20): warning CS1002: ; missing"/>
    <Exec Command="@echo Program.cs(13,20): Warning CS1003: ;; missing"/>
    <Exec Command="@echo Program.cs(14,20): error CS1004: ;;; missing"/>
</Target>
```

The TFS build fails, because it parses the output and sees an error reported in it.

I get the following output in buildlog.txt:

```
Program.cs(12,20): warning CS1002: ; missing
Program.cs(13,20): warning CS1003: ;; missing
Program.cs(14,20): error CS1004: ;;; missing
c:\bw\10\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(228,5): error MSB3073: The command "@echo Program.cs(14,20): error CS1004: ;;; missing" exited with code -1.
```

But I don't get these errors reported in the result details:

[image: TFS result after exec task containing warnings and errors]

While errors and warnings are reported on a normal project build with a link to a file containing the set with found warnings and errors:

[image: TFS result after normal project build containing warnings and errors]

Any idea on getting the list of errors and warnings parsed out of the exec output and into the TFS reporting?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question as follows:

I created a myexec.proj file that does the execution of the Exec.

In TFSBuild.proj I execute the solution using `<SolutionToBuild Include="myexec.proj"/>`.
The output is now automatically parsed for errors and warnings.

Comment: If this answered your question, please check it as the accepted answer.